# Unable to see sidekiq scheduled jobs on sidekiq webpage after adding newrelic_rpm gem to my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, newrelic

I have added newrelic_rpm gem to my rails application, after adding newrelic_rpm gem I am unable to see sidekiq jobs under scheduled tab in sidekiq webpage.

I have created newrelic.yml using the command and updated key and app name. No other config has been added/updated so far.
Am I missing any specific configuration related to sidekiq in newrelic.yml?
Note: Job is running after scheduled time of 1 minute but it is not visible on sidekiq webpage as it was showing earlier before adding the newrelic_rpm gem.
Ruby version: 3.1.2
Rails version: 6.1.4.2
newrelic_rpm gem version: 9.4.2
sidekiq gem version: 6.5.5

Comment: Are jobs visible again when you roll back the change? Are there any warnings, errors, or messages from Sidekiq or NewRelic written to the application's log file?

Comment: Yes if I roll back the change I can see the scheduled jobs on sidekiq web. With newrelic_rpm gem no logs are generating in sidekiq but in the rails-server logs as :Performed JobAbc (Job ID:- abc) from Async(default) but without newrelic_rpm gem I can see logs in sidekiq instead of rails-server logs as :Performed JobAbc (Job ID:- abc) from Sidekiq(default)